PgPool-II connections and better perfomance
I am using PgPool with 3 postgres nodes. Each postgres has been configured with max_connection = 2000, the pgpool with max_pool = 3 and num_init_children = 666.
Is there any guide to follow and set the best settings for better performance?
I saw on the internet that I need to follow this num_init_children * max_pool <= max_connection. That's true?

It is true , number of init children is equivalent to the number of pre forked processes that are readily available to serve your request , and each child process can cache upto x number of connections to the backend node which is max pool
hence if you were to consider the number of connections that can be handled by pgpool it ideally should be proportionate to the number of connections that can be handled by your backend node (postgres)
